# Define decorator without any runtime pollution

Tags: typescript

I want to define a decorator to mark properties for specific ESLint rules to be applied at dev time. After compilation there should be no sign of that decorator any more.

```
function notExistingAfterTSCompilation() {
  return function (target: any, propertyKey: string, descriptor: PropertyDescriptor) {
    // Returning the original descriptor without making any changes
    return descriptor;
  };
}
 
class ExampleClass {
  @notExistingAfterTSCompilation()
  method() {}
}
```

should compile to only:

```
class ExampleClass {
    method() { }
}
```

It might be smelly to try that at all. Any other suggestions?

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?experimentalDecorators=true&ssl=11&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABGOUCiAPGBnWYDmAgsFAKYBOAKgMoDCcAtgA4wA2AhrAgBQCUiAbwBQiROVJQQ5JKEhck3KO3L4JALkTswATwA0iJuThMKUbQGlS2jbnIwC+gCalsEO0yhxyGgApGT5GYAIi5uMB5e-MKiogD0sYgAShJSYPb4iFAAFqSIXjD49uysiM6u7p7kiADuMNlwIFCIDOwA1umaOogQWVqq2CIx4pLSpaEVXgDcgwC+0zMiQhAc2NiImOzMrKS0K2vRiAACKOhYuOnEZFR0jCwc8nyDDBJZcI58ggszQA)

---

---

ChatGpt suggested some jsdoc like comments:

```
class ExampleClass {
  /**
   * @assertions
   */
  markedProperty: string;

  constructor() {
    this.markedProperty = "Hello";
  }
}
```

Comment: "Mark" properties to what end? Could you use a _type_ instead?

Comment: If, at runtime, it exists, but does nothing, does it really exist? You're not going to convince the typescript compile to drop a decorator completely. But my point is, does that matter? Also: https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: I have written I want to mark properties for special `ESLint rules` to be applied at dev-time.

Comment: @jonrsharpe good idea. Something like [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghgJwNYDED2CCiBnAMgSwDtgAlAVwBsIAeAFQD4oBeKWgbgCgOBjCubbLBABhPgKgBvDlBlQAtiAAKCNGABcsRKgw4CxclWrZgCIgHNGLAOQBGKxwC+MoA) might work :/.

Comment: The JSDoc approach is indeed the usual solution. But it depends on what exactly you are trying to achieve. Sometimes you need something more structured.

Comment: ChatGPT actually hit the mark on this one. "Something that programmers and linting tools can see but that doesn't exist at runtime" is practically the definition of a comment.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it contains its own answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

ChatGpt suggested some jsdoc like comments could solve this problem, this is confirmed by other users in the comments section:

```
class ExampleClass {
  /**
   * @assertions
   */
  markedProperty: string;

  constructor() {
    this.markedProperty = "Hello";
  }
}
```